# Running Windows 10 Recovery caused my files to be deleted; how do I recover them?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ntfs, data-recovery, file-recovery

I have a dual boot Windows 7 and Linux Mint. I decided to upgrade to Windows 10 but I had the black screen with cursor issue. I power cycled my laptop and booted to Windows which showed me the windows logo with "Recovering..." at the bottom. I waited until it is finished but the black screen issue persisted.

I booted to Linux and opened the NTFS partition and all my previous data was deleted! and the free space of the partion increased (which means that the data wasn't stored in a backup folder).

I tried ntfsundelete but it didn't recover anything with importance.

Is there a way to recover my data? Thank you.

Comment: I think we can guess the answer, but just to have it completely clear: Are we to assume that you do not have any current backup of your files? Also, unless you happen to have a fresh backup that you are willing to just restore, *stop* using that computer right this moment until we work this out. Anything you do that causes disk writes (which is pretty much anything) will only serve to make recovery more difficult.